# UserDetailsService won't throw custom Exception

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, jsf-2.2

For my project I have used Spring 4.2.5, Spring Security 4.0.4 and JSF Mojarra. And I'll throw a custom exception from my custom UserDetailsService.

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException{

    com.entity.User domainUser = userDAO.getUser(login);

    boolean enabled = false;
    boolean accountNonExpired = true;
    boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
    boolean accountNonLocked = true;

    if(!enabled){
         throw new DisabledException("User is disabled!");
    }

    return new User(domainUser.getLogin(), 
                    domainUser.getPassword(), 
                    enabled, 
                    accountNonExpired,
                    credentialsNonExpired, 
                    accountNonLocked, 
                    getAuthorities(domainUser.getRole().getId()));
}
```

My LoginBean is:

```
public String login() {
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    FacesMessage msg = null;
    boolean loggedIn = false;

    try {
        SecurityContext secContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
        secContext.setAuthentication(auth);

        loggedIn = true;
        msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Welcome", username);
        return "/pages/index?faces-redirect=true";
    } catch (DisabledException e) {
        loggedIn = false;
        msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Login Error", e.getMessage());
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        loggedIn = false;
        msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Login Error", e.getMessage());
    }
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    context.addCallbackParam("loggedIn", loggedIn);
    return "/login";
}
```

So if I set "enabled" to true and provide right user credentials all works fine. But if I change it to false I can't see any exception in log and can't login.

I've try with this code. And it works fine but I can see only "Bad credentials" exception in any cases.

```
HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
httpReq.login(username, password);
```

I just started with java and spring, so can you explain me difference between **http Req.login(username, password)** and **getContext.setAuthentication(auth)**. In first case I can retrieve authenticated user and in second case I get anonymously authenticated user.

Which is right solution for user authentication and custom UserDetailsService.

P.S. I'm using java based config.

Sorry If this question was previously answered. I can't find working solution.

**UPDATE 1:**

If I comment this

```
if(!enabled){
     throw new DisabledException("User is disabled!");
}
```

In debug I can see default exception:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException: User is disabled
```

but I still can't catch this in my LoginBean. Why?

**UPDATE 2:**

I made some changes in my spring security config and now I can see locked, expired exceptions in my growl (primefaces) when I'm using **HttpServletRequest httpReq.login(username, password)**.

So how I can customize exception messages?
And I still can't understand difference between **HttpServletRequest login** and **UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication**.